# Auto generate REST API docs from Symfony

Tags: api, rest, symfony, documentation-generation

Is there an easy way to generate docs for REST api direct from a Symfony project?

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do it automatically. Most of the stuff should be defined in the routing, but that wouldn't work well for Documentation.

Comment: Seems like a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756978/how-to-document-a-symfony-based-rest-api-similar-to-enunciates-documentation-c/12609606#12609606) and is related to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315524/auto-documenting-rest-api-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for the post digging, but there is a Symfony bundle to help API doc generation, you can check out [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) which interconnects well with [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle).

The FOSRestBundle documentation provides sample bundles using both bundles to generate REST-ful web services and their documentation.

Comment: is there a way to document parameter types in Nelmio (ie form-data vs raw json etc)? see [here](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/issues/403)

Comment: I'd say you have to use the description for this specific use-case. You can format it in the markdown.

Comment: Is there any way to generate the annotations as well ?